# Mobile site version is zoomed and cropped

Tags: css

Recently i have created a new site with 'themify', the desktop and tablet versions turned out great and fit the screen perfectly. The phone version however appears to zoom into the home page, and when zoomed out manually my home page is cropped with a white border on the right site. Only the home page has this issue, every other mobile page on my site fits the screen perfectly.

URL: www.snapchataccountboosting.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you're missing a viewport tag, so the mobile browser tries to "see" the whole webpage at once. Try adding this to your `<head>`:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

You can read more about this tag and why it's useful [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)!